# forceActiveFocus() vs focus = true in QML

Tags: qt, focus, qml

I read the documentation about:

- [`focus` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#focus-prop)
- [`activeFocus` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#activeFocus-prop)
- [`forceActiveFocus()` method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#forceActiveFocus-method)
- [`FocusScope` object](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-focusscope.html#details)
- [and keyboard focus in QtQuick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-input-focus.html)

but it is still not clear when should someone use `forceActiveFocus()` method over setting the `focus` property to true or vice versa.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the [documentation states](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-input-focus.html#acquiring-focus-and-focus-scopes):

> For very simple cases simply setting the focus property is sometimes sufficient.

Such a simple case would be, if the `Item` which gets `focus: true` is not enclosed by a `FocusScope` that might have not the focus.

Then it continues with:

> > Within each focus scope one object may have Item::focus set to true. If more than one Item has the focus property set, the last type to set the focus will have the focus and the others are unset, similar to when there are no focus scopes.
>
> > When a focus scope receives active focus, the contained type with focus set (if any) also gets the active focus. If this type is also a FocusScope, the proxying behavior continues. Both the focus scope and the sub-focused item will have the activeFocus property set.

From where we learn, about the fact that setting `focus: true` is not sufficient, if it is for an `Item` that is a successor to a `FocusScope` as this `FocusScope` would need to have `activeFocus` su that the successor `Item` will receive `activeFocus`. This is recursive, and means, that the `FocusScope` will need to have `focus: true` and a possible predecessor `FocusScope` needs the `activeFocus` and so on. Which results in some kind of  *focus tree*

This *focus tree* consists out of *inner nodes* that are the `FocusScope`s and *leafs* that are `Item`s. A `FocusScope` might be a *leaf* as well, but I don't know why it should.

In this tree, each `FocusScope` may have up to one *child node* (either `Item` (*leaf*) or `FocusScope` (*inner node*) that has `focus === true`. Traversing this tree, following the path where all traversed nodes have `focus === true` the traversed nodes have also `activeFocus === true`. As each `FocusScope` may have only up to one *child node* with `focus === true` there is only one such path.

```
Column {
    FocusScope {
        focus: false
        width: 100
        height: 100
        Text {
            focus: true
            text: 'has focus ' + focus + '\nhas activeFocus ' + activeFocus
        }
    }
    FocusScope {
        focus: true
        width: 100
        height: 100
        Text {
            focus: true
            text: 'has focus ' + focus + '\nhas activeFocus ' + activeFocus
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have two `FocusScope`s. Both have a child that has `focus`, but as only the second `FocusScope` has the `focus` itself, it's child has `activeFocus`.

The use of `forceActiveFocus()` traverses the focus tree, and sets `focus` to  `true` for each node on the way, so the `Item` has `activeFocus` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! This is how I understand the docs as well. My confusion comes from the example what they provide under the Acquiring Focus and FocusScopes section in the Keyboard Focus in QtQuick doc. There instead of using forceActiveFocus method on the onClick event of the MouseArea, they set the focus explicitly to true (focus = true). Is this only a personal preference or just a simplification due to the simple example?

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope I could clarify that `focus = true` has not necessarily the same effect as `forceActiveFocus()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did a couple dummy examples and printed the focus and activeFocus properties to the console just to clarify myself if I understood you and the docs correctly. I think I am getting the hang of it.