# QML: Set focus TextInput in a table cell

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a table which can contain a TextInput or a ComboBox in a Column and I want to 'tab' through these rows and input my data. How can i force the table to only give focus to the TextInput or Comboboxes instead of the whole row?
Weirdly enough, if I click into each TextInput once, the behavior is nearly what i want, I can navigate through the inputs with the key arrows up and down, I'm guessing the row "remembers" the last focused item.

Here is how the table looks (only the 'Value' column is editable):
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25ITo.png)

Here is the code for the TextInput:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import ".."

FocusScope {
    property alias text: textInput.text
    property alias font: textInput.font
    x: rectangle.x; y: rectangle.y
    width: rectangle.width; height: rectangle.height

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.color: Style.table.itemBorderColor
        color: textInput.activeFocus ? "lightgray" : "white"

        TextInput {
            id: textInput
            focus: true
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.leftMargin: 5
            anchors.rightMargin: 5
            color: parent.enabled ? "grey" : ""
            selectByMouse: true
            enabled: parent.enabled
            clip: true

            font.pixelSize: Style.fontSize
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a abbreviated version on how the table loads the delegate:

```
StepTableView {
    ...

    TableViewColumn {
        id: tcValue
        role: "value"
        title: qsTr("Value")

        delegate:   Component {
            Loader {
                sourceComponent: {
                    // can happen if the model has not loaded yet
                    if (model === undefined || model === null || parent === null ) {
                        return;
                    }

                    return Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.0;" +
                                              "Component {" +
                                              "Item { Component.onCompleted: loadComponent(this, model, styleData)}}", parent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe that is one of cases when `Item.forceActiveFocus()` helps. Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487731/forceactivefocus-vs-focus-true-in-qml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I don't know  if there is a simpler solution but here is mine:

Since I don't know how to get the actual Item from the currentRow, I added a QHash to my model which stores the row index and the containing Object (e.g. a TextInput):

```
bool BacktraceTableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role /* = Qt::EditRole */)
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (role == FocusObjectRole)
    {
        focusObjectList_.insert(index.row(), value);
        return true;
    }
...
}
```

Table QML:

```
TableView {
    function navigateUp(event, tabToPrevious) {
        console.log("navigation: " + currentRow);
        if (currentRow > 0) {
            currentRow--;
            var focusObject = model.get(currentRow).focusObject;
            if (typeof(focusObject) != 'undefined') {
                focusObject.forceActiveFocus();
                event.accepted = true;
            } else {
                console.log("Cannot get focus object for row: " + currentRow);
            }
        } else {
            if (tabToPrevious) {
                KeyNavigation.backtab.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }
    }

    function navigateDown(event, tabToNext) {
        console.log("navigation: " + currentRow);
        if (currentRow < rowCount - 1) {
            currentRow++;
            var focusObject = model.get(currentRow).focusObject;
            if (typeof(focusObject) != 'undefined') {
                focusObject.forceActiveFocus();
            } else {
                console.log("Cannot get focus object for row: " + currentRow);
            }
        } else {
            if (tabToNext) {
                KeyNavigation.tab.forceActiveFocus();
            }
        }
    }

    Keys.onUpPressed: navigateUp(event, false)
    Keys.onDownPressed:navigateDown(event, false)
    Keys.onTabPressed: navigateDown(event, true)
    Keys.onBacktabPressed: navigateUp(event, true)

    onFocusChanged: {
        console.log("navigation: " + currentRow);
        if (activeFocus) {
            // on first table focus the currentRow = -1
            currentRow = currentRow > 0 ? currentRow : 0;
            var focusObject = model.get(currentRow).focusObject;
            if (typeof(focusObject) != 'undefined') {
                focusObject.forceActiveFocus();
            } else {
                console.log("Cannot get focus object for row: " + currentRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

The `navigateUp` and `navigateDown` functions in the TableView change the currentRow and get the QML Item out of the model which then gets the active focus.

If the Tab/Backtab Key is pressed and the model is at its end or beginning the next element in `KeyNavigation.tab` gets the focus, so you are able to tab out of the table.

The `onFocusChanged` event handles the event if you "tab into" the table, which then gives focus to the last select row or the first one.